# Replacing a jquery toggle button with an image

Tags: jquery, toggle

I would like to replace the toggle button with an image. I was wondering if there is a way to do this by simply adding a background to the  code. Ideally I would like to simply add something like < button background="url">

Here is the code I am using:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();

  });
});
</script>

<button>Basic</button>
<div class="basic1" style="display:none;">
<p>SAMPLE TEXT....</p>
</div>

<button>Advanced</button>
<div class="basic1" style="display:none;">
<p>SAMPLE TEXT....</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Use the css `background-image` assigned to a class then swap classes for your button.

Comment: Are there any other ways you can think of to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bno6z6fz/)

The key things to do are:

1. Use a div instead of a `<button>`
2. Use `background:url()` to add a background image. *Ensure the div is large enough (height/width) to contain the image or the image will not show*
3. Use jQuery to make the button click

**HTML:**

```
<div id="btnBasic">Basic</div>
<div class="basic1" style="display:none;">
    <p>SAMPLE TEXT....</p>
</div>

<div id="btnAdv">Advanced</div>
<div class="basic1" style="display:none;">
    <p>SAMPLE TEXT....</p>
</div>
```

**js/jQuery:**

```
$("div[id^='btn']").click(function(){
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#btnBasic{height:42px;width:150px;background:url(http://placekitten.com/g/148/40) no-repeat;color:yellow;font-weight:bold;padding:5px 30px;}
#btnAdv{height:42px;width:150px;background:url(http://placekitten.com/g/146/38) no-repeat;color:yellow;font-weight:bold;padding:5px 30px;}
div[id^='btn']:hover{cursor:pointer;}
```